# Windows 8 brightness meter is wrong

Tags: windows-8, laptop, display, brightness

This has been bothering me for a while, and I thought: I might as well ask.

When I lower my screen brightness with the corresponding FN-key, Windows 8 shows me this neat little meter in the top left corner of my screen. And indeed, as my screen dims, the meter goes down.
However, when the meter reaches its lowest point, I can still further lower my screen brightness (about three or four taps of the FN-key).

And with my screen at its darkest and the meter still at its lowest, I can increase the brightness and the meter goes up. But again, when it reaches its highest point... you guessed it: I can still make my screen go brighter (again: three or four taps brighter).

This doesn't really cause any problems, but it does drive me nuts. Is there any way as to calibrate this meter?

Comment: It sounds like this is a meter from your drivers that doesn't correlate with windows 8, but with windows 7. Maybe a driver-update works, but may also be unfixable.

Comment: It could be that the issue isn't one of calibration, but of displaying a useful range.  If most usage is varied in the middle range and the meter covers the entire range, there would be less visible distinction in the range that gets the most use.  PS - if that's the biggest thing driving you nuts, you are leading a charmed life.